# Do not find a regex in another regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a String that contains `"45+d6-1D10+47-12+1-7+106-100+100d100+151d258754"`
I need to extract all the numbers that are not followed or preceded by the letter d or D.
The matches i want here are :

```
45, 47, -12, 1, -7, 106, -100
```

My first wrong regex is `([\-]?(?!\d*[dD])(?!\d*[dD]\d)(\d+))` and it matches numbers after the d.

Could you please help me. I tried to use lookbehind but you can't use a quantifier inside a lookbehind.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you tried uses 2 negative lookaheads, which assert that only from the current position directly to the right there are no optional digits followed by `[dD]` and a digit.

Note that this `([\-]?` can be written as `-?`

---

To match not `D` or `d` at the left and right, you could use

```
-?(?<![dD\d])\d+(?![dD\d])
```

- `-?` Match an optional `-`
- `(?<![dD\d])` Negative lookbehind, assert not `d` `D` or a digit to the left
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?![dD\d])` Negative lookahead, assert not `d` `D` or a digit to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2OftsU/1)

```
import re

s = "45+d6-1D10+47-12+1-7+106-100+100d100+151d258754"
pattern = r"-?(?<![dD\d])\d+(?![dD\d])"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['45', '47', '-12', '1', '-7', '106', '-100']
```

Or you could use only word boundaries if there should be no word chars at the left and right as suggested by [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) in the comments.

```
-?\b\d+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccdjTd/1)

```
import re

s = "45+d6-1D10+47-12+1-7+106-100+100d100+151d258754"
pattern = r"-?\b\d+\b"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['45', '47', '-12', '1', '-7', '106', '-100']
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, \b is new to me^^

Comment: Why not just `r'-?\b\d+\b'`?